# Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: add-on

I installed vwm_secure_files and now when I try and edit ANY channel field I am getting this error and cannot do anything

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to locate the model you have specified: vwm_secure_files_m

EE. 2.5.3
VWM Secure Files .3

Comment: Have you posted a support thread on devot:ee, where this add-on has [official developer support](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vwm-secure-files)? This sounds more like a bug report to me.

Comment: I'd agree with Derek that this sounds most like a bug

Answer (score 2):

This is an EE bug. They changes some things in EE 2.5.3, which has effected almost all of my add-ons. Definitely contact the developer, it's a relatively easy fix. In my case I just abandoned the `$this->EE->load->model()` method entirely, along with the config too. It's entirely unreliable. It particularly fails in `__construct()` methods.

Here is how I usually fix the code.

```
 require_once PATH_THIRD . 'your_addon/models/your_model.php';
 $this->EE->your_model = new Your_model();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the module is not registered when the model is called. We just need to check it is registered or not.

Open "vwm_secure_files\models\vwm_secure_files_m.php" look for this line 
`class Vwm_secure_files_m extends CI_Model {`

add the following code above it:

```
if ( ! class_exists('Vwm_secure_files_m'))    {
    require_once realpath(rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), "/") . '/../mod.vwm_secure_files.php');
}
```

Please note I was using: EE 2.5.2